# Calculate size of iOS framework using Swift script

Tags: ios, swift, scripting, frameworks, filesize

I have a Swift script I'm writing to calculate the file size of an iOS framework. However, I have weird results. In one framework I have this file structure as shown in the Finder:

```
/{FrameworkName}.framework/Modules/{FrameworkName}.swiftmodule/
/{FrameworkName}.framework/Modules/{FrameworkName}.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule
/{FrameworkName}.framework/Modules/{FrameworkName}.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftdoc
```

HOWEVER! If I run code to calculate file size in my Swift script, as I'm looping through the files I see these files:

```
/{FrameworkName}.framework/Modules/{FrameworkName}.swiftmodule/
/{FrameworkName}.framework/Modules/{FrameworkName}.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule
/{FrameworkName}.framework/Modules/{FrameworkName}.swiftmodule/arm.swiftmodule
/{FrameworkName}.framework/Modules/{FrameworkName}.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftdoc
/{FrameworkName}.framework/Modules/{FrameworkName}.swiftmodule/arm.swiftdoc
```

As you can see, the files seem to split into 2 different files per architecture that is not shown in the Finder. The problem here is that both of those `arm` and `arm64` files are counted with the same size, therefore double counting my file size for the iOS Framework!

Right now I'm thinking this may be a bug in how Swift is looping through the file structure, but maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Here's my file size calculation code:

```
var bool: ObjCBool = false
  if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: documentsDirectoryURL.path, isDirectory: &bool), bool.boolValue {
    var folderSize = 0
    FileManager.default.enumerator(at: documentsDirectoryURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: [.<key_here>], options: [])?.forEach {
      folderSize += (try? ($0 as? URL)?.resourceValues(forKeys: [.<key_here>]))??.<key_here> ?? 0
    }

    return Int64(folderSize)
  }
```

Comment: No, your framework has 32 bit and 64 bit ARM architecture outputs. On x86 it has only 64 bit. Only one of the ARM modules will be used by a particular device.  If you install the app from the app store on the device then the appropriate architecture will be installed.  If you download the app via iTunes (Which is no longer possible with the new iTunes) then both architectures would be downloaded.  You could probably just look at the size of the arm64 file and ignore the 32 bit file

Comment: But why is the Finder showing only the `x86_64` whereas the Script finds them both?

Comment: For x86 (simulator) there is only a 64 bit build. For a device build (arm) there is both a 32bit and a 64but build.